# EPG from multicast save to xml or any other file

Tags: vlc, multicast, iptv, epg

i'm wondering how to save EPG from live transsimition over multicast. I've tryed with VLC but he dumps into some strange code.. Also i've trying with tv_grab_dvb-0.9 and have problems with save file. Any suggestions, or maybe solutions? Thx, for reading!!

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!